# Were other sins possible in the paradise?

Tags: sin, adam-and-eve, original-sin

Except for not eating from the tree of knowledge were there any other things that Adam and Eve weren't allowed to do or was everything else allowed?

Comment: -1 because the garden of Eden story is a easy read unless you're looking for extra-Biblical responses.  With that said, who would you like to receive answers from?

Comment: I've read it but I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adam and Eve were given only one restriction but they were also given a few instructions.  They were to "tend and dress" the garden, and they were to multiply and replenish the earth.  Failure to do these things would also have been contrary to the word of God and thus a sin.

Eating of the fruit of the tree of knowledge of good and evil was the only sin that carried a promised punishment; "in that day you shall surely die".

There existed, certainly, many other evil things that should not have been done in the garden.  Adam must not kill Eve.  But there was no need to give that sort of instruction since he had not yet been influenced by Satan and had not learned to kill, to lie, to hate, etc.  These sins would have been a possibility for you and I but not for Adam who was in a state of innocence.

Comment: They would be unable to sin without Satan?

Comment: @user13676: Good question. You've opened up a whole can of worms, but that's OK. One of the things which makes your question unanswerable, in a sense, is what you might call the "mystery of iniquity" (see 2 Thessalonians 2:7). There IS something mysterious about sin. Well meaning people have been trying for millennia to come up with a biblical and satisfying answer to the problem of sin. (The technical term for such an answer is theodicy.) Not-so-well-meaning people use the problem of sin and its obvious repercussions throughout the world (death, disease, natural disasters, and so on)

Comment: as an excuse for not believing in God. "How could a loving God afflict a child with incurable cancer?" they ask. Good question. We Christians dare not treat such questions cavalierly and simply quote Romans 8:28, for example, and leave it at that. That said, would our first parents be unable to sin were Satan completely out of the picture? My answer: Of course not! It's a moot point, however, because Satan has been a part of the picture for ages, and he was "successful" in tempting Eve. The rest is history. If God has his "druthers," would he have preferred our first parents not sin?

Comment: @user13676: If the only influence they are subject to is that of God, sin cannot enter in.  Satan was cast out of heaven but allowed into the Garden and subsequently the world to balance God's influence, leaving man free to choose the one or the other.

Comment: Of course! They DID, however, and God didn't have a back-up plan; rather, he had a "plan A" which he conceived before time but implemented IN time and in the FULLNESS of time (see Galatians 4:4). He did all this according to the purpose of his will, and one day sin will no longer exist in God's kingdom because Satan WILL be out of the picture forever. After all, "To this end was the Son of God manifested, that he might destroy the works of the devil" (1 John 3:8).

Comment: If killing Eve was not a sin, how could it be evil? The usage of 'evil' in the context, especially when it appears to run contrary to the first position, seems dubious.